# Separate sentences ending with a scientific reference number in r

Tags: r, regex, tokenize, sentence

I am working on a project where one of the steps is to separate text of scientific articles into sentences. For this, I am using `textrank` which I understands it looks for `.`  or `?`  or `!`  etc. to identify end of the sentence of tokenization.

The problem I am running into is sentences that end with a period followed directly by a reference number (that also might be in brackets). The examples below represent the patterns I identified and collected so far.

```
xx = c ("hello.1 World", "hello.1,2 World",  "hello.(1) world", "hello.(1,2) World", "hello.[1,2] World", "hello.[1] World")
```

I did some search and it looks like "Sentence boundary detection" is a science by itself that can get complex and domain specific.

The only way I can think of to fix this problem (in my case at least), is to write a regex that adds a space after the period so the `textrank` can identify it using its usual pattern.

any suggestions how to do that with regex in R? I tried my  best to search online but I could not find an answer.

This question explains how to add space between lower case followed by upper case. [Add space between two letters in a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896971/add-space-between-two-letters-in-a-string-in-r/26897007)
in my case, I believe I will need to add space between letter followed by period    and   number /bracket.

My expected output is something like:

```
("hello. 1 World", "hello. 1,2 World",  "hello. (1) world", "hello. (1,2) World", "hello. [1,2] World", "hello. [1] World")
```

Thank you

Comment: Would this help? [`\.(?=[[(]?\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/vffKdU/1). Replace each match with `. ` i.e., a dot followed by space

Comment: @GurmanjotSingh thanks a lot. This works. and thanks for sending the link to regex 101, this way I can understand it and change it if I encounter variations in this pattern.

Comment: one slight change I made is to add `\D` so I do not add space to decimal points. `\D\.(?=[[(]?\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/vffKdU/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the exact sample inputs you gave us, you may do a regex search on the following pattern:

```regex
\.(?=\d+|\(\d+(?:,\d+)*\)|\[\d+(?:,\d+)*\])
```

and then replace with dot followed by a single space.  Sample script:

```
xx <- c("hello.1 World", "hello.1,2 World", "hello.(1) world", "hello.(1,2) World",
        "hello.[1,2] World", "hello.[1] World")
output <- gsub("\\.(?=\\d+|\\(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*\\)|\\[\\d+(?:,\\d+)*\\])", ". ", xx, perl=TRUE)
output

[1] "hello. 1 World"     "hello. 1,2 World"   "hello. (1) world"
[4] "hello. (1,2) World" "hello. [1,2] World" "hello. [1] World"
```